# How to call a service of a seperate package from a node frm another package?

Tags: ros, ros-arduino-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the rosarduino bridge package on a custom robot and i'm developing a node access the package when required. but im havin trouble callin the services in arduinobridge usin rospy.serviceproxy('   ', )

shld it be called usin another function in da client node.. i did add da dependacies in da node.

This is da code I used to call the service

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import rospy
from ros_arduino_python import *
from ros_arduino_msgs.srv import *

def digital_write_client(pin, value):
  # rospy.wait_for_sevice('digital_write')
   try:
        digital_write = rospy.ServiceProxy('digital_write', DigitalWrite)
        digital_write(pin,value)
        print"call success"
   except rospy.ServiceException, e:
        print "Service call failed: %s"%e   

if __name__ == "__main__":
   digital_write_client(8,1)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259910/how-to-call-a-service-of-a-seperate-package-from-a-node-frm-another-package?/) by [maxsteel777](https://answers.ros.org/users/30115/maxsteel777/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-04-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-04-21**:
Which service are you trying to call? What happens when you try to call it? Do you get a python stack trace?

**Comment by [maxsteel777](https://answers.ros.org/users/30115/maxsteel777/) on 2017-04-21**:
i'm tryin to call DigitalWrite.srv using the below code, but i keep gettin da exception i have implemented. I'm new to ROS so having trouble

## rospy.wait_for_sevice('digital_write')

try:
digital_write = rospy.ServiceProxy('digital_write', DigitalWrite)
digital_write(pin,value)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-04-22**:
Please **edit your question** with the full program that you're trying to run, and the full exception that you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found da error in the code. I had been usin the wrong service name (rospy.ServiceProxy('digital_write', DigitalWrite). I changed it to 'arduino/digital_write' and its workin fine. Thank you

---

Originally posted by [maxsteel777](https://answers.ros.org/users/30115/maxsteel777/) with karma: 16 on 2017-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0